# fhir extension, which is an array of objects

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to understand how should I implement an extension field, which should contain array/list of "Objects". Currently the specs say that the extension can only contain "one of these 23":

```
  "valueInteger" : <integer>
  "valueDecimal" : <decimal>
  "valueDateTime" : "<dateTime>"
  "valueDate" : "<date>"
  "valueInstant" : "<instant>"
  "valueString" : "<string>"
  "valueUri" : "<uri>"
  "valueBoolean" : <boolean>
  "valueCode" : "<code>"
  "valueBase64Binary" : "<base64Binary>"
  "valueCoding" : { Coding }
  "valueCodeableConcept" : { CodeableConcept }
  "valueAttachment" : { Attachment }
  "valueIdentifier" : { Identifier }
  "valueQuantity" : { Quantity }
  "valueRange" : { Range }
  "valuePeriod" : { Period }
  "valueRatio" : { Ratio }
  "valueHumanName" : { HumanName }
  "valueAddress" : { Address }
  "valueContactPoint" : { ContactPoint }
  "valueSchedule" : { Schedule }
  "valueReference" : { Reference }
```

I would need something like

```
{
  "extension": {
     "url": "list-of-things", 
     "valueArray" : [
          {"code":"123","value":"Yellow"},
          {"code":"333","value":"Cab"}
     ]
  }
}
```

Could you point me to the correct direction, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extension values can't be arrays - it's too hard to handle repeating polymorphic types.  So repeating structures are handled by repeating the extension element and declaring the same URL.  Complex structures are handled using nested extensions.  Extensions that are defined as declared children of a complex extension don't need to have a full URL declaration.

Your structure would look like this:

```
{
  "extension: [{
    "url": "http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/list-of-things",
    "extension" [{
      "url": "code",
      "valueCode": "123"
    },
    {
      "url": "value",
      "valueString": "Yellow"
    }]
  },
  {
    "url": "http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/list-of-things",
    "extension" [{
      "url": "code",
      "valueCode": "333"
    },
    {
      "url": "value",
      "valueString": "Cab"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: @lloyd-mckenzie Can you confirm to me that every occurence of the word "extension" here have to be replaced by the real name of the field you want to add ? e.g "Things"

Comment: Nope.  The property name is "extension".  The meaning of the element is conveyed by the URL.  In this case "code" and "value".  You can't invent your own property names in FHIR.  Those are fixed.  (From an XML perspective there's a single schema per resource that fixes all element names.)

Comment: Can you suggest how to handle array of strings?
[ "yellow","Cab"]

Comment: You can't.  You have an array of extensions.  So a separate extension repetition (same URL) for both 'yellow' and 'Cab'